# Apply-Task puts targetfile in wrong directory

Tags: apache, ant

I am about to create an apache ant target that compresses all my .js files with gzip. For now I came up with the following:

```
<target name="compress-js" description="Compressed JS files">
    <echo>Compressing JS files...</echo>
    <apply executable="gzip" parallel="false">
        <arg value="-c" />
        <arg value="--best" />
        <srcfile />
        <arg value=">" />
        <targetfile suffix=".${extension}" />
        <fileset dir="${js.dir}" includes="**/*.js" />
        <mapper type="identity" />
    </apply>
    <echo>OK!</echo>
</target>
```

Reading the files works correctly but the generated targetfile has the wrong path.

Given ${js.dir} is: /var/htdocs/js
and I start my ant target in some other directory the script above produces the following shell command:

```
gzip -c /var/htdocs/js/a/b/1.js > ./a/b/1.js
```

which is not correct. The targetfile should get the same absolute path as the sourcefile. I want it to produce the following line:

```
gzip -c /var/htdocs/js/a/b/1.js > /var/htdocs/js/a/b/1.js
```

Can someone tell me how to do this?

Comment: If you do that you're liable to truncate the files.  The shell will truncate on open for write, then open them for read - but they're now truncated - as the source for the gzip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use something like =

```
<tar destfile="./your.tar.gz" compression="gzip">
 <tarfileset dir="${js.dir}">
  <include name="**/*.js"/>
 </tarfileset>
 </tar>
</target>
```

see [Ant manual for tar task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/tar.html)

Beside that there is also a wrapper task for the YUI Compressor Task, here's some detailled description how to use it =
[Compress JavaScript and CSS as Part of your Build Process](http://claude.betancourt.us/compress-javascript-and-css-as-part-of-your-build-process/)

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with two steps: first gzip the files, then rename them to remove the suffix.

```
<target name="compress-js">
  <apply executable="gzip" parallel="false">
    <srcfile/>
    <fileset dir="${js.dir}" includes="**/*.js"/>
  </apply>
  <move todir="${js.dir}">
    <fileset dir="${js.dir}">
       <include name="**/*.gz"/>
    </fileset>
    <globmapper from="*.gz" to="*"/>
  </move>
</target>
```